# Nodejs Callback or eventEmitter

Tags: node.js, callback, eventemitter

Which is the best practice to write nodejs code.

There are so many callback in my current code and reduced the readability.

Any suggestion?

Comment: This question is more appropriate for a discussion forum than StackOverflow. "This question is not a good fit to our Q&A format. We expect answers to generally involve facts, references, or specific expertise; this question will likely solicit opinion, debate, arguments, polling, or extended discussion."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to look at some flow control libraries and articles in answer to this question: [Async programming paradigm with nodejs and redis-node](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6854070/async-programming-paradigm-with-nodejs-and-redis-node/6855232#6855232).

Answer (score 1):

**Callback**:  Use a callback if you just want to execute some code at a
certain time and you don't need to emit success or failure.

**EventEmitter**:  Use this if your object emits lots of types of events.